# Why is this code displaying the output even though it does not meet criteria?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The code is supposed to display all the numbers that meet the criteria. It is not complete, but I cannot figure out why it is displaying the numbers that are larger than 10 in the list box. For example, I will type a 2 into the text box and the MessageBox will show saying the number has to be bigger than 3 and it will not display the number in the list box. If I type a number bigger than 10 it will display the MessageBox saying that the number must be bigger than 10 but it will display it in the list box. I do not know why.

```
Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
    Dim input As String = txtNumber.Text

    If DataOk() Then
        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        lstOutput.Items.Add(input)
    End If

End Sub
Function DataOk() As Boolean
    Dim number As String = txtNumber.Text
    If number = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Must not be blank")
        txtNumber.Focus()
    ElseIf CInt(number) > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number must be less than 10")
        txtNumber.Focus()
    ElseIf CInt(number) < 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number must be greater than 3")
        txtNumber.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Add `Return False` in your first 2 conditions.  You should use `Integer.TryParse` instead of calling `CInt()`.

Comment: Two minutes in the debugger would have let you figure this out yourself. That's probably less time than it took you to write your post, and about double the time it's been when I'm typing this comment. You really should learn to use it. It will be the most important tool in your toolbox; you should figure out how to start using it sooner than later.

Comment: Okay adding `Return False` worked. I'm extremely novice at any coding in general. While I will concede that the debugger is a great tool if you know how to use it, but frankly the professors at my institution never use it and haven't shown us how to use it. I had one professor that tried to teach us how to use the Java debugging tool in Eclipse ONE time, but even then most of the class did not know how to use it.

Comment: Basic debugging requires only 2 things: a mouse and a thinking cap. a) click on the grayish gutter next to the first line of code in that method **or** right click and Insert Breakpoint.  b) Run the project   c) When the code gets to that like it will stop.  d) use the mouse to hover over variables and view their value e) Use the Debug toolbar or F8 (Step) to execute one line at a time and compare what you *thought* would happen to what the code really does.  It is a critical skill even an intern must know - you will spend more time debugging than coding.  Faster than posting on SO too.

Comment: It's irrelevant that your professor hasn't shown you how to use it. Did your professor show you how to use your keyboard or mouse? If you're going to write code, you need to learn to use the debugger. At the very least, it will show you what code is actually executing, which would have answered this question. As I said previously, the debugger will be *the most important tool in your toolbox*. If you're not willing to invest the time to learn *the most important tool you will ever use*, you should re-think your educational or career path.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting numbers added because there is no `Return False` if number is greater than 10. Hence True is returned. To solve your problem, update your code as below.

```
ElseIf CInt(number) > 10 Then
   MessageBox.Show("Number must be less than 10")
   txtNumber.Focus()
   Return False     ''please add this statement
ElseIf CInt(number) < 3 Then
```

You may rewrite the function as below.

```
Function DataOk() As Boolean
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim errMssg As String = ""

    If txtNumber.Text.Trim = "" Then
        errMssg = "Must not be blank"
    ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtNumber.Text.Trim, number) Then
        errMssg = "Provide a valid number"
    ElseIf number > 10 Then
        errMssg = "Number must be less than 10"
    ElseIf number < 3 Then
        errMssg = "Number must be greater than 3"
    End If

    If errMssg = "" Then
        Return True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(errMssg)
        Me.txtNumber.Focus()
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```